# Running PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio

How can I manage to make PulseAudio run under Ubuntu 11.10? From the Dash I search for PulseAudio, when I find it, I click on the icon and get the following reply:

```
Fatal Error: Unable to connect to PulseAudio
```

Answer (score 4):

Pulseaudio is included and configured for you already in Ubuntu 11.10 by default, you don't have to run it manually. If you are having problems connecting to Pulseaudio in a fresh install, you most likely have encountered a bug.